# django models : How to have variable number of foreign keys in a model?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, foreign-keys, relational-database

For instance, **Model Resume** contains variable number of **Model Project** 's,
What should be my models and relationships between them to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ultimately I want to store variable number of attributes(a list) in a table. 
Is this even possible in case of relational databases ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by storing variable number of attributes? Maybe you can explain more about what relationship you are modeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that what you need is a many-to-many relationship between **Resume** and **Project**, so I would suggest doing something like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # Project fields

class Resume(models.Model):
    # Resume fields
    projects = models.ManyToManyFields(Project, related_name='resumes')
```

Note that a default association table will be defined by Django under the hood this way.

And now you have a model in which a **resume** can be related with multiple **projects** and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You just need either a many to many field, or a foreign key from Model Project to Model Resume.